# Python virtualenv on MacOS apparently not activated

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, python-venv, virtualenv-commands

I have created and activated a `python` `virtualenv` on my MacOS.

I have also installed a list of modules as listed in my `requirements.txt`

A stripped down version of it is the following:

```
python-dotenv==1.0.1
```

this is also valided:

```
▶ pip freeze | grep -i dotenv
python-dotenv==1.0.1
(.venv)
```

However when I am trying to run my program, part of which has the following code

```py
from dotenv import find_dotenv, load_dotenv
```

I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is it possible that when you execute your python script, that you don't have your virtualenv activated?